# How do I find the action/class of an apk so I can launch it from the command line in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Given an .apk, is there a way to figure out how you could launch the application from within a terminal emulator in an android device?

E.g. for com.wondershare.player-1.apk

I have read that you probably want to run something like ...

```
am start -n com.wondershare.player/com.wondershare.player.<name of the activity or something?>
```

And I've also seen ...

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.wondershare.player/<name of class?>
```

Is there some where in the manifest or somewhere where I could look for hints to fill in the < blanks > in the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the developer tools, you can pull the APK off and run:

```
aapt dump badging <foo.apk>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the way i do is this,
Install Super Manager application, go to APK manager and then tap on the application and then you can see Activity Button in the menu below. This would give you all the activities and service of the application.